# How to change ipywidget animation speed during animation

Tags: animation, slider, ipywidgets, ipyleaflet

I am using jupyter notebook to animate a marker that moves along an ant path. I am using ipyleaflet and ipywidgets.
I have added a slider widget (speed_slider) to my map, to allow me change the speed of the animation. My animation is using a for loop code as shown in below code.

```
for i in ant_path.locations:
    mark.location = i
    sleep(speed_slider.value)
```

I am able to set the animation speed before running the cell that contains the above for loop code, but I am not able to change the speed during animation. Please any suggestions on how change the animation speed during the animation runtime, using the slider.

Comment: Please share your whole code. If the animation is causing blocking then the speed will not be able to be changed whilst the animation is running.

Comment: @ac24, thanks for your request. The full code is uploaded on github https://github.com/Oao2021/simulation-edge-computing.git The slider(Run Speed) and other sliders are only adjustable before running the python script for the simulation (in cell 22). I want to adjust the speed and other sliders during simulation run time, i.e. the sliders should be able to adjust the model parameters during run time

Comment: the base-model.ipynb can be used